# Difficulty understanding scissorstack class in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

The github page containing clipping (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping%2C-with-the-use-of-scissorstack) is very short. I can't seem to get my head around to using it. Is it possible for someone to explain in more depth and detail (examples are nice) on how to use this class?

I am trying to clip my game along the middle, and sepearte a left and right side of the screen. That way if an object spriteBatch drawing was to go through the middle, it would not render on the other side.

Thanks!

Comment: Something similar has been asked around before: 
[LibGdx ScissorStack Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887174/libgdx-scissorstack-example)
[LibGdx Cutting An Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275914/libgdx-cutting-an-image)